# AWS API Gateway as Serivce proxy for S3 upload

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have been reading about creating an API which can be used to upload objects directly to S3. I have followed the guides from Amazon with little success.

I am currently getting the following error:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

My API call configuration:

[image]

The role ARN assigned is not in the image, but has been set up and assigned.

Answer (score 5):

The "Missing Authentication Token" error can be interpreted as either

1. Enabling AWS_IAM authentication for your method and making a request to it without signing it with [SigV4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html), or
2. Hitting a non-existent path in your API.

For 1, if you use the generated SDK the signing is done for you.

For 2, if you're making raw http requests make sure you're making requests to `/<stage>/s3/{key}`

BTW, the path override for s3 puts needs to be `{bucket}/{key}`, not just `{key}`. You may need to create a two-level hierarchy with bucket as the parent, or just hardcode the bucket name in the path override if it will always be the same. See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html